# Android fragments and activities questions

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

This is sort of an extension from a previous question, but with more questions and less code ([Android starting another activity or calling a method from another class (using fragments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505344/android-starting-another-activity-or-calling-a-method-from-another-class-using)).  I'm trying to get a better idea of how fragments and activities work inside Android apps while writing a sample app of a navigation drawer combined with location API code.

As I understand it, the navigation drawer has to be created extending an Activity so as to do the UI components properly.  What I've done so far is broken down my UI panes into different fragments with different XML and Java files for each.  Java file builds the UI from the XML specified in it, and displays the content in the content pane while keeping the nav drawer in tact, similar to this:  http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/.

Each of those fragments, with the exception of "Home", needs code from the Location APIs/Location Activity, which is based on this MainActivity:  https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html.  However I am having two problems:

1. My Location Activity class has code onCreate to populate TextView variables from the UI.  But the UI is all handled by fragments.  So every time the Location Activity is created, those variables are null because the Activity doesn't seem communicate with the fragment UI.
2. The buttons in the fragments call methods that only exist in Location Activity.  And they don't seem to communicate with the activity, only their fragment Java class.

So first off, does this sound like the proper way to do this?  Using fragments to handle the options in the navigation drawer and producing content in the content pane?  If so, how do I make it work with the Location Activity?

Comment: Have you read this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html?

Comment: Yes.  My question is more specific to the nav drawer I think.  Don't I need to keep that activity running while a location activity is at the same time?

Comment: Incorporate location stuff into the main activity or use a service which is independent of any activity.  You can enabled/disable location services on fragment load/unload.

Comment: Agreed with @techiServices , why not combine DrawerActivity with LocationActivity? Sounds a lot more logical than having an activity in the background like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ive encountered what you are saying here in many aspects, and i don't think there is right and wrong here.. mostly because sometimes the work don't give you a free hand to do what you want.

1. answer:
   yes you are right, you have some kind of an "egg & the chicken" situation here, so, how to solve it :

a. lets assume that you don't want the user to do anything until you finish inflating the fragment, 
so the first action will be (ui/ux) showing a progress dialog.

b. for connivance matter only, assume you are adding or already add your fragment inside some kind of layout (lets say relative layout) ..
this layout can be extended to your own class see :
http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

now, at your special class you can use one of two (depending the moment you want to enter)
either -
    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
    }
or - 
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
(put in mind that onMeasure is the potential to be called many time and not only on the start.)

so, we have a view, that is being extended, which we can grep on the onCreate of our activity **even before it is being created and inflated**.
in this extended view i would add a public function like:

`public void setOnFinishInflatingTheChikenOrTheEggListener(IonFinished listenr)` ...

the IonFinished  will be a simple interface with a simple function, only to tell you that the view finish inflating himself on the screen.

c. now let your activity implements IonFinished, and pass it into the  setOnFinishInflatingTheChikenOrTheEggListener function as a param, save it there, and when one of the function we Override before is being called you can trigger this listener.

d. this function is been trigger in you activity, here it is safe to get you fragment, and do something with him.. cause you are sure all of your views is in place... (dont forget to dismiss dialog at this point).

(if you didnt understand, tell me and ill make an example for you...)

2.
answer:
lets continue with the second problem, this is much easier then before,
in your fragment you have buttons, to them you set an onClickListner ... 
in it you shoud use the following:

```
Activity activity =  getActivity();
if(activity!=null && activity instanceof LocationActivity ){
LocationActivity myLocationActivity = (LocationActivity)activity;
//****************************************************************
// call here to any public function in your activity, get set listeners, basically do anything.. 
}
```

hope it helps to understand more about fragments...